# Even though I have annotated with @Repository in my JpaRepository interface still I am getting the error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Currently I'm facing an issue in Autowire configuration between Repository and the service layer.

I'm unable to trace my mistakes.

## Repository - OrderRepository

```
package com.kakashi.orderservice.repository;

import com.kakashi.orderservice.model.Order;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository\<Order, Long\> {
}\`
```

## Service - OrderService

```
package com.kakashi.orderservice.service;

import com.kakashi.orderservice.dto.OrderLineItemsDto;
import com.kakashi.orderservice.dto.OrderRequest;
import com.kakashi.orderservice.model.Order;
import com.kakashi.orderservice.model.OrderLineItems;
import com.kakashi.orderservice.repository.OrderRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderService {

    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
    public void placeOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    
        List<OrderLineItems> orderLineItems = orderRequest.getOrderLineItemsDtoList()
                .stream()
                .map(orderLineItemsDto -> mapToDto(orderLineItemsDto)).toList();
    
        order.setOrderLineItemsList(orderLineItems);
    
        orderRepository.save(order) ;
    }
    
    private OrderLineItems mapToDto(OrderLineItemsDto orderLineItemsDto) {
        OrderLineItems orderLineItems = new OrderLineItems();
        orderLineItems.setPrice(orderLineItemsDto.getPrice());
        orderLineItems.setQuantity(orderLineItemsDto.getQuantity());
        orderLineItems.setSkuCode(orderLineItemsDto.getSkuCode());
    
        return orderLineItems;
    }

}
```

`

## But I am getting the Below error:#

```
\`\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.kakashi.orderservice.service.OrderService required a bean of type 'com.kakashi.orderservice.repository.OrderRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.kakashi.orderservice.repository.OrderRepository' in your configuration.
```

Please do guide me I am using java 17, here I am pasting my application.properties file and pom.xml for your reference

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order-service
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=""
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

server.port=8081
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kakashi</groupId>
    <artifactId>order-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Previously it was working fine, but I dunno why its misbehaving like this.

Comment: I think its Maven related Issue, aside those slashes at 
```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository\<Order, Long\> {
}\
```
I can't see anything wrong. Try to clean your project. There is a ``Maven`` tab on the right. From there there should be ``orderservice`` folder, next lifecycle and clean. If it happens that you moved files between packages it happiness sometimes than Maven is loosing track of it. If not, use a good ol' constructor in service and try ``@Autowire``

Comment: Yeah, that was the only problem... thanx man

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
```

on service class hope it would work.